# Apache Storm Bolt task is not receiving message after some time

Tags: java, apache-storm

We have a storm topology in which we configured one spout and two bolts. Spout queries data from DB continuously and send tuples it to first bolt for some processing. First bolt does some processing and send tuples it to second bolt which calls third party web service and sends data. So, what is happening after some time, last bolt is not getting any tuples and if we restart the topology it works fine. Only last bolt is in problem here. Other spout and first bolt are running fine, and I am not using acking framework. I have configured only one worker in this case`.

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("messageListenrSpout", new MessageListenerSpout(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("processorBolt", new ProcessorBolt(), 20).shuffleGrouping("messageListenrSpout");
    builder.setBolt("notifierBolt", new NotifierBolt(),40).shuffleGrouping("processorBolt");
    Config conf = new Config();
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_SLEEP_SPOUT_WAIT_STRATEGY_TIME_MS, 10000);
        //conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(600);
        conf.setDebug(true);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY, conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that you're having problems with a backlog of tuples causing timeouts.  Try increasing the parallelism hint for the 2nd bolt since it sounds like that one's process time is much longer than that of the first bolt (that's why there would be a backlog into the 2nd bolt).  If you're running this topology on the cluster look at the Storm UI to see the specifics.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am not using acking framework. Will storm still timeout the message?? If messages are getting timed out, where we can check the logs. And I have given parallelism hint to 30 of the last bolt.

Answer (score 2):

Guys when I was debugging my topology, I found that if let's say spout is sending message fast but bolt is processing slow. In this case, message will be queued up LMAX Disruptor Queue. Then spout task wait for that to be empty. If you take thread dump, you will find threads are in TIMED_WAITING state. So, we need to configure topology in such a way that its inflow and outflow maintained.